# Three.js ugly rendering effect

Tags: html, svg, d3.js, html5-canvas, three.js

I am trying to render 3D map of buildings with Three.js based on the 2D svg file. Basically, what I am doing is I take each path from svg, use transformSVGPath from d3.js to create shape and then extrude it, like that:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    shading: THREE.FlatShading,
    overdraw: 0.5
});
var obj = {
    name: id,
    shape: transformSVGPathExposed(el.path)
};
obj.shape3d = obj.shape.extrude({
    amount: 5,
    bevelEnabled: false
});
obj.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(obj.shape3d, material);
obj.mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
obj.mesh.scale.set(1,1,1);
obj.mesh.position.x = -750;
obj.mesh.position.z = -500;
obj.mesh.position.y = 20;
MapEngine.shops.push(obj);
```

transformSVGPathExposed is transformSVGPath function from d3.js exposed to be callable from outside. My svg file looks like this: [map svg](http://kojot.yaxint.com/mapg.svg). And rendering effect looks like this: [Three.js render](http://kojot.yaxint.com/rendering_effect.jpg)

What's the reason I am seeing those ugly nonsmooth meshes?

Comment: Live effect may be seen here: http://kojot.yaxint.com/tmtest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a well known problem with CanvasRenderer and is apparently by design. Workaround is to set material.overdraw to some non-zero value, like 0.35 (this parameter was recently changed from boolean to float). See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/3407

Other option is to switch to WebGLRenderer. It doesn't have that rendering problem, and is usually much faster.

Comment: thank you! i've just figured it out for myself that webGL renders everything nicely. i was stupid to not even try this.. thanks again for such a quick and accurate response, cheers!